# How to convert a binary date column date into gregorian date format in sql

Tags: sql, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

This i got to convert a single binary date to Gregorian date ,

```
Select to_char(to_date(sum(2415020+42744),'J'),'MMDDYYYY') Last_arrear_date from dual;
```

But I'm not able to convert a binary date column date into Gregorean in xyz table

For Example

Suppose i have a table borm,That has account_open_date column that stores data in binary format , I want to convert that account_open_date column data into Gregorian date format. Please let me know how to convert that

Comment: Please tag the dbms you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**While you have to change the entire column, Don't use the sum function**.

Try the below SQL command it will work.

```
select acct_no, to_char(to_date((account_open_date + 2415020), 'J'),'DD-MON-YYYY') 
from borm;
```

**To Change Binary to Gregorian**

```
select column1 ,...columnN, to_char(to_date((Column_name + 2415020), 'J'),'DD-MON-YYYY') 
from Table_Name 
WHERE Condition;
```

**To change Gregorian to Binary:**

```
select column1,columnN, to_char(to_date(Column_Name,'YYYYMMDD'),'J')-2415020 
from Table_Name 
where condition  ;
```